# Reactive Extensions: When and why to use the Notification class?

Tags: system.reactive

I am trying to understand when and why to use the Notification class. I see it is related to ToNotifier and FromNotifier, but not sure entirely of their use.

Is it for creating a two way like binding between a an observable sequence and the observer, so the observer can push changes back with notifications to the originating observable, or?

Thanks, Egil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time I've ever personally used `Notification<T>` was when I had to do some freaky error trapping across multiple merged streams...here's a trimmed down semi-unrealistic example of what I was doing:

```
public class ImportantException : Exception {}

var src1 = new Subject<int>();
var src2 = new Subject<int>();  
var wrapped = Observable.Merge(src1.Materialize(), src2.Materialize());

var query = 
    from note in wrapped
    let fail = note.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError
    let ignorable = fail && !(note.Exception is ImportantException)
    where !fail || !ignorable
    select note;

using(query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    src1.OnNext(1);
    src2.OnNext(1);
    src1.OnError(new Exception());
    src2.OnError(new ImportantException());
}
```

So basically, I only wanted certain types of errors from multiple (in my case, dozens) of merged streams to percolate out to the subscriber. Here's the output of the above unrealistic example:

```
OnNextNotification<int> { Value = 1 }
OnNextNotification<int> { Value = 1 }
OnErrorNotification<int> { Exception = (ImportantException) }
```

(and yes, you can replicate this with some tinkering, using `Catch` constructs, but I found it easier to read-through in this form)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote about Materialize and Notification a bit here:

http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=47

And also used it here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/bbcc1af9-64b4-456b-9038-a540cb5f5de5

Answer (score 1):

I started using it recently while trying to unit test the Rx queries in my app's services. I am now able to pass a `TestScheduler` to the service call being tested, have the Rx query generate events on the `TestScheduler`, which are then accessible to the unit test for inspection as a collection of `Notification<>` instances. You can see the approach in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/14/testing-rx-queries-using-virtual-time-scheduling.aspx), the **Testing Rx queries** section.